# QueryDSL + PathBuilder + cast to string

Tags: dynamic, casting, path, querydsl

I am filtering PrimeFaces DataTables using dynamic filters.I have this working using Spring `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification`.Now I am wondring how to do the same using QueryDSL.

Using specification I can use `javax.persistence.criteria.Root` to get a `javax.persistence.criteria.Join`, use `javax.persistence.criteria.Expression.as(Class<String> type)` to cast it to String and finally use `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.like(Expression<String> x, String pattern, char escapeChar)`.

How do I do the same in QueryDSL ? I can get PathBuilder using `new PathBuilder<T>(clazz, "entity")` (do you really have to use the variable here? I would like my class to be generic...) but then the `com.mysema.query.types.path.PathBuilder.get(String property)` returns new PathBuilder instead of an Expression.

If I try to use `com.mysema.query.types.path.PathBuilder.getString(String property)` I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer]`.

Seems like the part I am missing is the cast.
I'm quite sure someone was dealing with the same thing already.

Thanks.

**Edit: Stack trace for IllegalArgumentException**

Trying to search for text "1" inside integer column using `com.mysema.query.types.path.PathBuilder.getString(String property)` - that's where I need the cast to happen :

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.validateParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAUtil.setConstants(JPAUtil.java:44)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:130)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:97)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:102)
    ...`

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: @user1622058 Did you manage to work this out in the end?

Comment: In the end I created a DTO and assemble the Predicate manually using stringValue()...not the best way but haven't found a better one...

Comment: @user1622058: I have the same problem. Can you post your solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

To get a valid condition you will need to take the types of the properties into account, e.g.

```
pathBuilder.getNumber(Integer.class, property).stringValue().like(likePattern)
```

Comment: Sorry, was on vacation...I am aware of this but is there any way how to do this dynamically? My input is something like "property" but I don't know what type is this property in database so I do not know whether to call `getNumber` or `getBoolean` or `getDate` any other getter....

Answer (score 1):

I was researching a similar topic until I came across this aged question. I hope my answer will be helpful to some.

I think the possible solution lies (exclusively) outside of QueryDSL. You can use common Java reflection to obtain the field type, something like

```
Class type = clazz.getDeclaredField(criteria.getKey()).getType();
// don't forget to catch exception if field doesn't exist ..
switch(type.getSimpleName()) {
    case "String": 
         StringExpression exp =  entityPath.getString(...);
}
```

That way you can have a reasonably dynamic implementation.